# Import Error: C extension (pandas; python; ubuntu)

Tags: python, ubuntu, pandas, importerror

I am new to Linux and do not know how to fix this error.

```
$ python googledrive/scripts/test.py
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
      import __builtin__ as builtins
  ImportError: No module named '__builtin__'

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
      from pandas import hashtable, tslib, lib
    File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 53, in init pandas.tslib (pandas/tslib.c:102872)
    File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
      import http.client as httplib
    File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 71, in <module>
      import email.parser
    File "/home/michael/googledrive/scripts/email.py", line 4, in <module>
      import pandas.io.data as web
    File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/data.py", line 15, in <module>
      from pandas.compat import(
  ImportError: cannot import name 'bytes_to_str'

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "googledrive/scripts/test.py", line 11, in <module>
      main()
    File "googledrive/scripts/test.py", line 2, in main
      import pandas as pd
    File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
      "extensions first.".format(module))
  ImportError: C extension: 'bytes_to_str' not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.
```

Python 3.5.0 :: Anaconda 2.4.0 (64-bit)

I tried `conda install -f pandas` and it still hasn't fixed my issued.

googledrive/scripts/test.py

```
def main():
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data as web

all_data = {}

all_data['fb'] = web.DataReader('fb','yahoo','1/1/2015', '11/24/2015')

print(all_data['fb'])
```

I do not know which directory I should run the below suggestion.

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

I don't have any problem running the code line by line in the terminal, but only when I try to run my script file.

```
>>> print(all_data['fb'])
                  Open        High         Low       Close    Volume  \
Date                                                                   
2015-01-02   78.580002   78.930000   77.699997   78.449997  18177500   
2015-01-05   77.980003   79.250000   76.860001   77.190002  26452200   
2015-01-06   77.230003   77.589996   75.360001   76.150002  27399300
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try running `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` in `/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/`

Comment: ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: I figure out the issue. I had a python script I created called email.py that got picked up instead of the python module email.